# Docker doesn't create custom node-red image

Tags: docker, node-red

I'm new to docker and I've been trying to create a custom node-red image with custom flow for influxdb. Docker doesn't seem to use my dockerfile for the image creation.

This is my docker-compose:

```
node-red:
    container_name: node-red
    build: node-red
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - node-red-data:/tmp/node-red_data
    networks:
      - node-red-net
```

Then, inside a folder called node-red I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM nodered/node-red AS base

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY nodered_flow.json /data/flows.json


CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Both the package.json and the nodered_flow.json are in the same folder as the dockerfile. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: @paltaa the container is not even created

Comment: Where do you think the copy is putting the `package.json` (and what's in it?) Also what do you think is the working directory for the `npm install`?

Comment: @hardillb the package.json has the modules I need for the flow, such as the InfluxDB module. They both need to be installed in the /data folder

Comment: But that is not where you've put them, the default working directory is not `/data`

Answer (score 0):

In `service.build`, you need the path to the build context, in case the it is in the same directory you could use `.`. So this should work:

```
node-red:
    container_name: node-red
    build: .
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - node-red-data:/tmp/node-red_data
    networks:
      - node-red-net
```

For more information check: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build

Comment: While doing this, I got the error npm WARN saveError EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/node-red/package.json. Any ideia what this might be?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is wrong, it's putting your `package.json` in `/usr/src/node-red` and when you run `npm install` it will remove Node-RED.

It should look like this:

```
FROM nodered/node-red AS base

WORKDIR /data
COPY package.json /data
COPY nodered_flow.json /data/flows.json
RUN npm install --only=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/node-red
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it still gives me an error of "npm WARN saveError EACCES: permission denied, open '/data/package.json'"

Comment: That exact file works perfectly fine with a local `package.json` and `nodered_flow.json`. Double check the local file permissions on `package.json` or maybe add `--chown=node-red` between `COPY` and `package.json /data`